# Teechart CSeriesStatsTool Retriving data

Tags: activex, teechart

Can anyone let me know how to use CSeriesStatsTool for getting the data such as mean, Median, Std. Dev.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statistics tool makes easy to add basic functions to series, like Average, Trend, etc.And also shows a report with basic statistical information about the selected series. You can find a simple example in the TeeChartActiveX Demo project, concretely, **All feature\Tools\SeriesStats** or taking a look in next simple example of code:

```
  Private Sub Form_Load()
    With TChart1
        .AddSeries scLine
        .Series(0).FillSampleValues 100
        .Tools.Add tcSeriesStats
        .Tools.Items(0).asSeriesStats.Series = TChart1.Series(0)
        ' Add a series to be used for an Average Function
        .AddSeries scLine
        'Define the Function Type for the new Series
        .Series(1).SetFunction tfAverage
        .Series(1).DataSource = .Series(0)
     Text1.Text = .Tools.Items(0).asSeriesStats.Statistics.Text
    End With

End Sub
```

I hope will help

Thanks,

Comment: I can't add a new series, Actually I want only the data which is present in the info tab of statistics tool, can you let me know how Can I retrieve this.

Comment: Hello Akshay Bhalla, 
If you want the info, to get it you only need do something as do, in next line of code Text1.Text = TChart1.Tools.Items(0).asSeriesStats.Statistics.Text,therefore, you only need access to the Statistics text of your series.